# В чем проблема при очистки памяти?

Tags: c++, qt, динамические-массивы

У меня было задание по написанию программы которая при вводе числа в поле и при нажатии на кнопку добавляет лейбл с числом которые было введено в поле в layout. Я это реализовал через динамическую память и массивы(такое было задание, без всяких векторов и подобных вещей)
вот код:

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    int NumberOfOrders = 0;
    int theNumber;
    QLabel *OrderList;
    QLabel *SyncArr;



private slots:
    void on_SumbitNumber_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;

    delete [] OrderList;
    delete OrderList;

    delete [] SyncArr;
    delete SyncArr;
}



void MainWindow::on_SumbitNumber_clicked()
{


    if (NumberOfOrders > 0) {
    delete [] OrderList;
    }

    NumberOfOrders+=1;
    OrderList = new QLabel[NumberOfOrders];

    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfOrders-1;i++) {
        OrderList[i].setNum(SyncArr[i].text().toInt());
    }
    if (NumberOfOrders > 1) {
    delete [] SyncArr;
    }
    SyncArr = new QLabel[NumberOfOrders];

    theNumber = ui->OrderNumberInput->toPlainText().toInt();
    OrderList[NumberOfOrders-1].setNum(theNumber);
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfOrders; i++) {
    ui->OrdersScreen->addWidget(&OrderList[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfOrders;i++) {
        SyncArr[i].setNum(OrderList[i].text().toInt());
    }
    if (NumberOfOrders>4) {
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfOrders; i++) {
            qDebug() <<OrderList[i].text().toInt();
        }
    }
}

//orderscreen - layout для добавление, OrderNumberInput - поле для ввода числа
```

Все работает прекрасно но я заметил в предыдущих программах что если ты работаешь с динамической памятью и массивами и если я где то ее или что то забываю очистить или удалить то после программы возникает ошибка в маке. Так вот после этой программы ошибка тоже возникает и я не понимаю почему. Пожалуйста не надо давать способы решить это задачу по другому или через вектора или что то другое, мне нужно решить именно так и я решил и остается только исправить ошибку с очищением памяти. Помогите пожалуйста что я пропустил и где что не удалил?

Comment: ну для начла, что это за бред: `delete [] OrderList; delete OrderList;`?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch ну вроде так в первом мы очищаем массив, а во втором сам указатель удаляем?)) разве не так?))))

Comment: вы бы сначала базу подтянули по с++...

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch да я просто не так это понял, извиняюсь)) Ответ не дочитал просто уже вывод сделал

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не хватает кучи кода, но ошибки и так видны. Операторы `new`/`new[]` должны быть с парными `delete`/`delete[]`.

Смотрим на `OrderList`. К сожалению, его объявления нет, но его можно догадаться. Удаляете Вы его сразу двумя способами (видимо для надежности:) ). А нужно явно только одним. Создавался через `new[]`, значит удалять нужно только так - `delete[] OrderList;`.

С `SyncArr` такая же история.

Также нужно помнить, что delete с точки зрения пользователя "не знает", вызывалось ли для переменной delete. Поэтому, если вызвать два раза подряд для переменной, которая не nullptr, вот где то так

```
SyncArr = new QLabel[NumberOfOrders];
delete [] SyncArr;
delete SyncArr;
```

Вы гарантированно получите проблему. Она может не сразу проявится, но бывает всякое - так как тут двойное UB - двойное освобождение ещё и неправильным (непарным) delete.

Comment: Спасибо большое но я не понял вот это "Смотрим на OrderList. К сожалению, его объявления нет, но его можно догадаться." Объявление идет же в файле mainwindow.h? Или вы не про это?

Comment: посмотрел ещё раз и увидел. странно.

Comment: Можете пожалуйста сказать что не так?) Мне надо создавать их прямо в кнопке чтоле?

Comment: не понимаю вопроса

Comment: Я не очень понимаю то что вы сказали "Смотрим на OrderList. К сожалению, его объявления нет, но его можно догадаться" и "посмотрел ещё раз и увидел. странно." Это вы про что говорите не очень понимаю

Comment: я имею ввиду, что когда я писал ответ, я почему то не увидел объявления OrderList. и я не знаю почему. Но это не проблема догадаться, как именно он должен выглядеть, что бы код компилировался. Это меня и удивило.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113393/discussion-between-leocoolguy-0-and-kovadim).

Answer (score 4):

Почитайте про очистку памяти в `Qt`.

Если коротко: `Qt` сам очищает память. Вот есть главный класс `MainWindow` который находится в `статик. памяти` и он сам удаляется по принципу `С++`. А его "дети" которые находится в `динам. памяти` сами удаляются.

Советую прочитать так как подробности я не описывал.

Comment: Но в ручную все равно что то надо очищать наверное? Просто если я  не удаляю это в ручную то мне мой комп сам ошибку про программу выдает,что то по типу ошибка в памяти

Comment: Да, удаляет, если явно об этом попросить. Для того, что бы бы MainWindow удалил, нужно либо в smart pointer завернуть, либо сделать объекты дочерними к MainWindow. Ни того, ни другого не сделано.

Comment: @KoVadim Надо сделать вот так: `QLabel* label = new QLabel("Какой-то текст", this);` Это гораздо легче чем вручную)

Comment: да, можно и так. Но лучше ui элементы не создавать ручками. Скорее всего здесь есть другой вариант - к примеру, использовать grid

Comment: @KoVadim ну извини, я просто книгу щас читаю по Qt и уже отвык от Designer. Там онли ручками всё